# How to combine cell value to column name with CASE logic in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, case

I have two VIEWS where data is represented as below:

**VIEW 1**

```
| username   |  function   |   level      | location       | 
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:| :-------------:|
| John       |   Operation |  Country     | United Kingdom | 
| John       |   Operation |  Area        | South West     |
| John       |   Operation |  Shop        | 0001           |
```

**VIEW 2**

```
| shop       |  region     |   country       |    area        | 
|:-----------|------------:|:---------------:| :-------------:|
| 1200       |   u1        |  United Kingdom |    West        | 
| 1201       |   u2        |  United Kingdom |    West        |
| 1000       |   f1        |  France         |  South West    | 
| 1100       |   i1        |  Italy          |  South West    |
| 1111       |   s1        |  Spain          |  South West    | 
| 1112       |   n2        |  Norway         |  South West    |
| 0001       |   o1        |  Japan          |  Asia          |
```

The relation between the two VIEWs are that each AREA has more than one Country, each Country has more than one REGION, each REGION has more than one shop.

**Trying to:**  Generate a view where for each user from the top table data all rows will be generated from the bottom table depending on the LEVEL selection on the top table. So in this case the VIEW should show

**Expected Result**: So in this case the VIEW should show all the SHOPS, REGIONS, COUNTRIES under AREA South West, all the SHOPS and REGIONS under COUNTRY United Kingdom and the SHOP 0001.

```
| username   |  function   |   level         |    location    | 
|:-----------|------------:|:---------------:| :-------------:|
| John       |   Operation |    shop         |    0001        |
| John       |   Operation |    shop         |    1001        |
| John       |   Operation |    shop         |    ...         |
| John       |   Operation |    Country      |  United Kingdom|
| John       |   Operation |    Country      |    ...         |
| John       |   Operation |    Country      |    ...         |
| John       |   Operation |    Region       |    ...         |
| John       |   Operation |    Region       |    ...         |
| John       |   Operation |    Region       |    ...         |
| John       |   Operation |    Area         |    South West  | 
| John       |   Operation |    Area         |    ...         | 
| John       |   Operation |    Area         |    ...         |
```

Not sure how this can be done with CASE statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should have at least completed the `location` column in your expected output.  You should start by figuring out how to join the two views together; I can't see an easy way of doing this.

Comment: I am a little puzzled. In View 1 John is in Country United Kingdom, Area South West  and Shop  0001.  In View 2 Shop 0001 is in Japan, which is in area Asia.  United Kingdom is in area West, whilst area South West includes other european countries?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock You are correct. Having access to 0001 shop means in the RESULT there should be a row for John where Level would be SHOP and location would be 0001. VIEW 1 means John has access to all shops under UK, All countrie, regions and shops under Area "SOUTH WEST" and the SHOP 0001 which happens to be under the COUNTRY japan, AREA asia and region o1. Here AREA west has other countries under it, COUNTRY has multiple REGIONS under it and REGIONS has SHOPS under them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will require a union of four separate queries:

- The first query should select all shops equal to or under the shops/regions/countries/areas specified in the first table that join to the second table.
- The second query should select all regions equal to or under the regions/countries/areas specified in the first table that join to the second table.
- The third query should select all countries equal to or under the countries/areas specified in the first table that join to the second table.
- The fourth query should select all areas specified in the first table that join to the second table.

There could be duplicates within each query, so we should use `distinct` within each query to eliminate them. There cannot be duplicates between the queries, so we can use `union all` rather than `union`.

---

```
create table userop (username varchar(32), [function] varchar(32), level varchar(32), location varchar(32) );
create table shopgeo (shop varchar(32), region varchar(32), country varchar(32), area varchar(32) );

insert into userop (username,[function],level,location) values
    ('John','Operation','Country','United Kingdom'),
    ('John','Operation','Area','South West'),
    ('John','Operation','Shop','0001')
;

insert into shopgeo (shop,region,country,area) values
    ('1200','u1','United Kingdom','West'),
    ('1201','u2','United Kingdom','West'),
    ('1000','f1','France','South West'),
    ('1100','i1','Italy','South West'),
    ('1111','s1','Spain','South West'),
    ('1112','n2','Norway','South West'),
    ('0001','o1','Japan','Asia')
;

-- show base tables
select * from userop;
select * from shopgeo;

-- solution
select * from (
    select distinct o.username, o.[function], 'shop' level, g.shop location from userop o inner join shopgeo g on o.location=case when o.level='Area' then g.area when o.level='Country' then g.country when o.level='Region' then g.region when o.level='Shop' then g.shop end
    union all select distinct o.username, o.[function], 'region' level, g.region from userop o inner join shopgeo g on o.location=case when o.level='Area' then g.area when o.level='Country' then g.country when o.level='Region' then g.region end
    union all select distinct o.username, o.[function], 'country' level, g.country from userop o inner join shopgeo g on o.location=case when o.level='Area' then g.area when o.level='Country' then g.country end
    union all select distinct o.username, o.[function], 'area' level, g.area from userop o inner join shopgeo g on o.location=case when o.level='Area' then g.area end
) t1 order by username, case when level='shop' then 1 when level='country' then 2 when level='region' then 3 when level='area' then 4 end, location;
```

[image: output]

Comment: As expected. Thanks for such a simple yet effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did it slightly differently

```
DECLARE @user varchar(50) = 'John'

Declare @view1 table (
username varchar(50),
ufunction varchar(50),
ulevel varchar(50),
location varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @view1 VALUES ('John', 'Operation', 'Country', 'United Kingdom')
INSERT INTO @view1 VALUES ('John', 'Operation', 'Area', 'South West')
INSERT INTO @view1 VALUES ('John', 'Operation', 'Shop', '0001')

Declare @view2 table (
shop varchar(50),
region char(2),
country varchar(50),
area varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('1200', 'u1', 'United Kingdom', 'West')
INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('1201', 'u2', 'United Kingdom', 'West')
INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('1000', 'f1', 'France', 'South West')
INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('1100', 'i1', 'Italy', 'South West')
INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('1111', 's1', 'Spain', 'South West')
INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('1112', 'n2', 'Norway', 'South West')
INSERT INTO @view2 VALUES ('0001', 'o1', 'Japan', 'Asia')

SELECT username, ufunction, v1.ulevel, location AS Shop, v2.region, v2.country, v2.area from @view1 v1 
INNER JOIN @view2 v2 ON v1.location = v2.shop
WHERE v1.ulevel = 'Shop' AND username = @user
UNION
SELECT v1.username, v1.ufunction, v1.ulevel, v2.shop, v2.region, v2.country, v2.area from @view1 v1
INNER JOIN @view2 v2 ON v1.location = v2.area
WHERE v1.ulevel = 'Area' AND username = @user
UNION
SELECT v1.username, v1.ufunction, v1.ulevel, v2.shop, v2.region, v2.country, v2.area from @view1 v1
INNER JOIN @view2 v2 ON v1.location = v2.country
WHERE v1.ulevel = 'Country' AND username = @user
```

RESULT

```
username    ufunction   ulevel  Shop    region  country         area
John        Operation   Area    1000    f1      France          South West
John        Operation   Area    1100    i1      Italy           South West
John        Operation   Area    1111    s1      Spain           South West
John        Operation   Area    1112    n2      Norway          South West
John        Operation   Country 1200    u1      United Kingdom  West
John        Operation   Country 1201    u2      United Kingdom  West
John        Operation   Shop    0001    o1      Japan           Asia
```

The idea being that you list all the shops just once, but that within each record you can read off what right gives the user access to that shop, be it "Shop", "Area" or "Country"