# How to return all rows from one SQL table when condition matches on other table with no link

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There are two tables.

**Table 1:**

```
bankid     region   country continent   area
-----------------------------------------------
1101       Puglia   Italy   Europe      South West
1222       Atos     France  Europe      South West
2222       Atos     Japan   Asia        East
0101       Momba    Gana    Africa      South East
...        ...       ...     ...        ...
```

**Table 2:**

```
user        level   geography   function
-------------------------------------------
anthony     Global  World        Buy
anothony    Global  World        Sell
smith       bankid  2222         Buy
smith       bankid  2222         Sell
```

Rules:

There are COUNTRIES under AREAS, REGIONS under COUNTRIES, BANKS under each REGION. So the expected result for the query is

> Return all the AREAS, COUNTRIES, REGIONS, BANKIDs from T1 when T2.level='Global' and all the FUNCTIONs in T2

What I am trying to do is return all the rows from **Table 1** when level = 'Global'. However, the expected format is as follows:

```
user        level   geography   function
-------------------------------------------
anthony     bankid  1101         Buy
anthony     bankid  1222         Buy
anthony     bankid  2222         Buy
anthony     bankid  0101         Buy
anthony     region  Puglia       Buy
anthony     region  Atos         Buy
anthony     region  Momba        Buy
anthony     country Italy        Buy
anthony     country France       Buy
anthony     country Japan        Buy
anthony     country Gana         Buy
anthony     are     South West   Buy
anthony     are     East         Buy
anthony     are     South East   Buy
smith       bankid  ....         Sell
smnith      region  ....         Sell
smith       country ....         Sell
smith       area    ....         Sell
```

**Problem:** How to query the result when there is no link between the two tables?

Tried:

```
    SELECT ua.username, ua.[function], ua.level, ua.geography 
FROM Table2 ua INNER JOIN 
(SELECT bankid, region, country, area, 'Global' as Global FROM Table1) as  c
                ON ua.geography=CASE WHEN ua.level='Area' THEN c.area 
                                              WHEN ua.level='Country' THEN c.country 
                                              WHEN ua.level='Region' THEN c.region
                                              WHEN ua.level='bankid' THEN c.bankid 

                                        END
```

With no luck.

Comment: School assignment? Show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Can you show expected output sample

Comment: How does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017835/how-to-combine-cell-value-to-column-name-with-case-logic-in-sql  What do you really want?

Comment: Is the database schema under your control?

Comment: TheGameiswar: Everything from the Table1 for the username of Table2. 

@JonathanWillcock The difference is there is no column name in Table 2 that matches T1.level = 'Global' to link the both tables and return results mainly from the Table2 rows as Table1 column. 

Taemyr : yes

Comment: @TheGameiswar : Some sample expected result added to the post.

Comment: I think you want a `cross join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the desired result:

```
--Create Table1
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [bankid] [int] NULL,
    [region] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [continent] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [area] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
GO
--Create Table2
CREATE TABLE [Table2](
    [username] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [level] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [geography] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [function] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
GO
--Insert sample records in Table1
INSERT [Table1] ([bankid], [region], [country], [continent], [area]) 
VALUES  (1101, N'Puglia', N'Italy', N'Europe', N'South West'),
        (1222, N'Atos', N'France', N'Europe', N'South West'),
        (2222, N'Atos', N'Japan', N'Asia', N'East'),
        (101, N'Momba', N'Gana', N'Africa', N'South East')
GO
--Insert sample records in Table2
INSERT [Table2] ([username], [level], [geography], [function]) 
VALUES (N'anthony', N'Global', N'World', N'Buy'),
       (N'anothony', N'Global', N'World', N'Sell'),
       (N'smith', N'bankid', N'2222', N'Buy'),
       (N'smith', N'bankid', N'2222', N'Sell')


--Query
WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT 'bankid' level ,CAST(bankid AS NVARCHAR(50)) geography FROM Table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT DISTINCT 'region' level ,region geography FROM Table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT DISTINCT 'country' level ,country geography FROM Table1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT DISTINCT 'area' level , area geography FROM Table1
             )
    SELECT  t2.username ,
            IIF(t2.level = 'Global', CTE.level , CTE2.level) level,
            IIF(t2.level = 'Global',CTE.geography ,CTE2.geography) geography,
            t2.[function]
    FROM    Table2 t2
            LEFT JOIN CTE ON t2.level = 'Global'
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                level ,
                                '....' geography
                        FROM    CTE
                      ) CTE2 ON t2.level <> 'Global';
```